How can I increase the resolution of the device stream in Android Studio Jellyfish?
I am streaming my android device(Lenovo Tab K10 having android OS version 12) in to my Android Studio  Jellyfish after mirroring it.
But the video quality is very poor.
How can fix it? How can I increase stream resolution?
Please check the attached screenshot.
I did not find any solution.
when I record screen of the device using the same tool in android studio, I am geting better quality.
I am expecting to stream my device live with better screen resolution.


I recommended that you use https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy

Use this command for SCRCPY to increase the bitRate scrcpy --max-size 1920 --bit-rate 8M


If that doesn't work, try this:

Increase your bitRate a little bit more scrcpy --bit-rate 16M
You can set a specific resolution scrcpy --max-size 2560
Set your resolution at fullscreen mode scrcpy --fullscreen

I hope it has been helpful and that it works for you.
☺️

I do not want to use a separate tool for it.

exactly, you can't do layout inspection with scrcpy, only possible with Android Studio built-in mirroring
